# apt-get 404 error?

Tags: debian, apt

Hi I'm trying to install

```
sudo apt-get install libmagick++-6.q16-5v5
```

My OS is

```
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

When I try to run apt-get update I get the following error.

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I ignore this and try to install the libMagick but got the following error

```
    E: Unable to locate package libmagick++-6.q16-5v5
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libmagick++-6.q16-5v5'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmagick++-6.q16-5v5
```

Is there anything else I can do to get this to install? thanks advance.

Comment: 1. You're running Debian, so remove the ppa entry for Ubuntu and try again. 2. Do you really need that the precise version of `libmagick++`?

Comment: @roaima good point. I'm on a docker and must have mistakenly added this because I assumed it was an ubuntu dis. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following repository `http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu` doesn't support `groovy` codename, that's why you get `404 error`. All supported codename are [listed here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/).

The `libmagick++` can be installed on Debian Buster through:

```
sudo apt install libmagick++-6.q16-8
```

[`libmagick++-6.q16-5v5`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libmagick++-6.q16-5v5) belongs to Ubuntu Xenial.

Comment: thanks this solved it.  As commented above I made a mistake by putting in ppa for ubuntu.  So apt update works now after removing it. However, thanks to your answer I now have libmagick installed.

Answer (score 0):

(Converted from comment.)

You're running Debian, so remove the ppa entry for Ubuntu and try again.

Do you really need that the precise version of `libmagick++`? If not, try installing `libmagick++` rather than `libmagick++-6.q16-5v5`